# Identifier 'i' has already been declared problem

Tags: javascript, html

I try to do a accordion for display content and i get this problem on mi js code, I'm sure it's an easy problem to fix, but I can't see it right now, I need help to see it.

JS code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("servicon-button");
var i;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

My html of this:

```
<button class="servicon-button"> <img src="icons/computer.svg" alt=""> </button>
<div class="panel">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try declaring the `i` variable inside the `for loop`, putting the variable inside the for loop ensures that the variable is only used inside the loop which is a good thing, if you put it outside, it will mix with other variables in the code in the global scopes which can cause problems like reassigning or redeclaring variables

```js
const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("servicon-button");

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

sidenote : `var` is not really recommended, use `const` and `let` instead

Comment: @VLAZ putting the variable inside the for loop ensures that the variable is only used inside the loop which is a good thing, if you put it outside, it will mix with other variables in the code in the global scopes which can cause problems like reassigning or redeclaring variables

Comment: Right, but why are you telling *me* and not OP? I was prompting you to add more explanation to your answer rather than "do this, it's magic".

Comment: ow yeah xD hold on i will edit my answer hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring `var i` before the loop, declare it inside the `for` loop like this:
`for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) { ...` This is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Why is the position of the declaration a problem? 1. There is no other declaration. 2. It's declared as `var`, so re-declaration will not cause an error *unless* it's redeclared with `let` or `const` in the same block scope. There is no such code here.

Comment: @VLAZ there is probably another declaration in the code, he only shows a small code snippet not the whole code and we dont know if there is another declaration in his code